# How to write a function square_odd_terms?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a function `square_odd_terms` that accepts a tuple as an argument and returns a tuple with the odd terms in the tuple squared. Even terms will remain the same.
>
> For example, `square_odd_terms((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))` returns  `(1, 2, 9, 4, 25)` and `square_odd_terms((2, 4, 6, 8, 10))` returns  `(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)`.
>
> Answer format:
>
> ```
> def square_odd_terms(tpl):
>    # Fill in your code here
> ```

I only can write a function that returns you the value of the sum of odd numbers:

```
def sum_odd_squares(tree):
    if tree == ():
        return 0
    elif is_leaf(tree):
        if tree%2 == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return tree ** 2
    else:
        return sum_odd_squares(tree[0])+sum_odd_squares(tree[1:])

def is_leaf(item):
    return type(item) != tuple
```

How to do this question? How to modify the above code such that it fulfills the question requirement? What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Posting Homework Questions here, huh?

Here is one way to do the problem:

- Create a result tuple(empty)
- Iterate through each item in your input tuple, using a loop.
- Check if tupleValue[i] is odd or even.
- If even, simply add it to result tuple.
- If odd, compute the square and add to result tuple.
- return the result tuple

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[ x**2 if x%2==1 else x   for x in tpl ]
```

However, this creates a list, not a tuple. To create a tuple, you can either convert the result:

```
tuple([ x**2 if x%2==1 else x   for x in tpl ])
```

Or simply use a generator expression in the first place:

```
tuple( x**2 if x%2==1 else x   for x in tpl )
```